# Why did Lucene IndexWriter did not update the index when called from a Web Module?

Tags: java, lucene

I have a strange problem with a Web Project using Lucene. 
I have written a bean which writes the data of a business object into Lucene.  The business data is provided by the web front end. This all works very fine. 
But in some rarely cases the business object is not added into the index. It seems that this happens in cases when multiple users are accessing the bean.

My bean uses static methods creating the Lucene IndexWriter and creating a Lucene Document on base of my business object. 
I thought making all methods static is enough to become thread save. But now I wonder if it is necessary to make my update method also 'synchronized' to avoid conflicts with other threads? 
In the cases when the object is not written into the index there are no exceptions thrown from lucene. So I can not say what happens behind my layer.

My update method looks like this:

```
public static boolean updateWorklist(ItemCollection workitem) throws PluginException {

        IndexWriter awriter = null;
        // try loading imixs-search properties
        Properties prop = loadProperties();
        if (prop.isEmpty())
            return false;

        try {
            awriter = createIndexWriter(prop);

            // create term
            Term term = new Term("$uniqueid", workitem.getItemValueString("$uniqueid"));
            // test if document should be indexed or not
            if (matchConditions(prop, workitem)) {
                logger.fine("add workitem '" + workitem.getItemValueString(EntityService.UNIQUEID) + "' into index");
                awriter.updateDocument(term, createDocument(workitem));
            } else {
                logger.fine("remove workitem '" + workitem.getItemValueString(EntityService.UNIQUEID) + "' into index");
                awriter.deleteDocuments(term);
            }
        } catch (IOException luceneEx) {
            // close writer!
            logger.warning(" Lucene Exception : " + luceneEx.getMessage());

            throw new PluginException(LucenePlugin.class.getSimpleName(), INVALID_INDEX,
                    "Unable to update search index", luceneEx);

        } finally {

            if (awriter != null) {
                logger.fine(" close writer");
                try {
                    awriter.close();
                } catch (CorruptIndexException e) {
                    throw new PluginException(LucenePlugin.class.getSimpleName(), INVALID_INDEX,
                            "Unable to update search index", e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new PluginException(LucenePlugin.class.getSimpleName(), INVALID_INDEX,
                            "Unable to update search index", e);
                }

            }
        }

        logger.fine(" update worklist successfull");
        return true;
    }

.....

    public static IndexWriter createIndexWriter(Properties prop)
            throws IOException {

        /**
         * Read configuration
         */
        // String sLuceneVersion = prop.getProperty("Version", "LUCENE_45");

        String sIndexDir = prop.getProperty("lucence.indexDir");
        String sFulltextFieldList = prop
                .getProperty("lucence.fulltextFieldList");
        String sIndexFieldListAnalyse = prop
                .getProperty("lucence.indexFieldListAnalyze");
        String sIndexFieldListNoAnalyse = prop
                .getProperty("lucence.indexFieldListNoAnalyze");

        logger.fine("IndexDir:" + sIndexDir);
        logger.fine("FulltextFieldList:" + sFulltextFieldList);
        logger.fine("IndexFieldListAnalyse:" + sIndexFieldListAnalyse);
        logger.fine("IndexFieldListNoAnalyse:" + sIndexFieldListNoAnalyse);
        // compute search field list
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(sFulltextFieldList, ",");
        searchFieldList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            String sName = st.nextToken().toLowerCase();
            // do not add internal fields
            if (!"$uniqueid".equals(sName) && !"$readaccess".equals(sName))
                searchFieldList.add(sName);
        }

        // compute Index field list (Analyze)
        st = new StringTokenizer(sIndexFieldListAnalyse, ",");
        indexFieldListAnalyse = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            String sName = st.nextToken().toLowerCase();
            // do not add internal fields
            if (!"$uniqueid".equals(sName) && !"$readaccess".equals(sName))
                indexFieldListAnalyse.add(sName);
        }

        // compute Index field list (Analyze)
        st = new StringTokenizer(sIndexFieldListNoAnalyse, ",");
        indexFieldListNoAnalyse = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            String sName = st.nextToken().toLowerCase();
            // do not add internal fields
            if (!"$uniqueid".equals(sName) && !"$readaccess".equals(sName))
                indexFieldListNoAnalyse.add(sName);
        }

        /**
         * Now create a IndexWriter Instance
         */
        Directory indexDir = createIndexDirectory(prop);

        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
        IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(
                Version.LATEST, analyzer);

        // set the WriteLockTimeout to wait for a write lock (in milliseconds)
        // for this instance. 10 seconds!
        indexWriterConfig.setWriteLockTimeout(10000);

        return new IndexWriter(indexDir, indexWriterConfig);
    }

....

public static boolean matchConditions(Properties prop, ItemCollection aworktiem) {

    String typePattern = prop.getProperty("lucence.matchingType");
    String processIDPattern = prop.getProperty("lucence.matchingProcessID");

    String type = aworktiem.getItemValueString("Type");
    String sPid = aworktiem.getItemValueInteger("$Processid") + "";

    // test type pattern
    if (typePattern != null && !"".equals(typePattern) && !type.matches(typePattern)) {
        logger.fine("Lucene type '" + type + "' did not match pattern '" + typePattern + "'");
        return false;
    }

    // test $processid pattern
    if (processIDPattern != null && !"".equals(processIDPattern) && !sPid.matches(processIDPattern)) {
        logger.fine("Lucene $processid '" + sPid + "' did not match pattern '" + processIDPattern + "'");

        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

....
**Edit 20.Jan:** 
I added the IndexWriter method into the code example. My property file is empty and did not provide any lucene settings to the IndexWriter

**Edit 21.Jan:** 
I added the matchConditions method

Comment: do you observe any exceptions ? e.g. LockObtainFailedException

Comment: Unfortunately no exception occur in case the index is not written.

Comment: do you re-open your index readers after update ? because if not your changes will not be visible

Comment: also you can use single IndexWriter, it is thread safe

Comment: you will be threadsave if you use "synchronized".

Comment: can you please post your "createIndexWriter" and the propertie-file?

Comment: I added my createIndexWriter method into the code example. I do not provide any properties in my propery file for lucene.

Comment: Thanks so far for your suggestions. But what is now the right answer? Should I implement a kind of Singleton pattern or just adding the keyword synchronized to my update method? Or is the problem located somewahre else.

Comment: I don't see how you use searchFieldList and indexFieldListNoAnalyse. I presume they are used in the matchConditions method. Then probably you might want to get rid of race conditions. Because when one thread invokes createIndexWriter it re-assign those lists and before it fills them another thread can see them empty.

Also I would recommend using singleton IndexWriter since it is ineffective to create it for each request.

Comment: @maksim07: thanks for your last comment. What did you mean with '...using singleton IndexWriter'? Did you mean that I should use the Singleton Pattern for my bean class? As I am running in a EJB container, and I consider to use the 'singleton' annotation from EJB 3.1. which would make it very easy in implementation.

Comment: I meant you should use singleton pattern for IndexWriter, initialise it once and re-use. It should be threadsafe. Just curious,  was it race condition ? How exactly do you observe that some objects was not added to the index ? e.g. do you see "remove workitem" log messages ?

Comment: The problem is, that the document is simply not added into the index - without any exceptions. This happens maybe one or two times in a month in the production environment. So it is not possible to trace or debug this since I setup a test case which is near to the production scenario to reproduce the case.

Comment: you should definitely initialize the following static variables just once: searchFieldList, indexFieldListAnalyse, indexFieldListNoAnalyse. Can you show your matchConditions method please ?

Comment: I added the origin code from my matchConditions method also.

Comment: Now I implemented a new singleton EJB and I hope this will solve the problem. You can see the implementation of this EJB [here](https://github.com/imixs/imixs-workflow/blob/master/imixs-workflow-engine/src/main/java/org/imixs/workflow/plugins/jee/extended/LuceneUpdateService.java).

Comment: I'm afraid it won't solve the issue. The createDocument method can observe empty searchFieldList, indexFieldListAnalyse, indexFieldListNoAnalyse collections since there is a race condition. I think you can avoid it if you put the code from createIdexWriter method into init method.

Comment: thanks again. I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @maksim07, the problem in my implementation was the use of static variables and methods. So the createDocument method could observe empty searchFieldList, indexFieldListAnalyse, indexFieldListNoAnalyse collections since there was a race condition.

Finally I re-implemented the code by using the singleton pattern with a separate init() method where I initialized all the values of my member variables. 
Using a Singleton EJB makes the usage of a singleton pattern very easy and guaranties that all method calls are synchronized by the default behavior of the EJB container.