# What is the difference between Singleton Pattern and Synchronized

Tags: java, design-patterns, concurrency

I have a problem with "thread safe" method calls in one of my Java EE Beans concerning using the Lucene `IndexWriter`.

I am unsure if I should solve my problem by implementing a **Singleton Pattern** or if it is sufficient to add the keyword `synchronized` to my bean methods.

Can anybody explain what exactly is the difference?

Comment: Its hard to recommend unless you clarify about your , **a problem**? both are two different things ( though related in some way ) so list your code or elaborate more about your problem.

Comment: if speed is not a big problem for that specific method(e.g. method is very fast) then, singleton pattern make life easy

Comment: do you mean "thread safe"?

Comment: One is a pattern and the other is a keyword. There isn't any similarities so it not clear what the confusion is. It's like asking what is the difference between parking a car (a technique) and a spark plug (a feature of the engine)  and which one should I use?

Answer (score 2):

Singleton creates exactly one instance of a class. As long as it isn’t referenced by itself.

As an example of a non-thread-safe method:

```
public class Singleton {

  private static Singleton instance;
  private Singleton () {}

  public static Singleton getInstance () {
    if (Singleton.instance == null) {
      Singleton.instance = new Singleton ();
    }
    return Singleton.instance;
  }
}
```

The problem with this is: If more than one thread execute getInstance simultaneously for the first time, the constructor of `Singleton` is called more than once. So the singleton would not be a singleton and subsequent errors are very hard to detect.

Examples of a thread-safe method:

```
public class Singleton {

  private static Singleton instance;
  private Singleton () {}
  public static synchronized Singleton getInstance () {
    if (Singleton.instance == null) {
      Singleton.instance = new Singleton ();
    }
    return Singleton.instance;
  }
}
```

The bad thing about this method is that for every access the `getInstance` method is called (so one thread could block others).

Last but not least the synchronized version:

```
public class Singleton {
  private static final class InstanceHolder {
    static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
  }
  private Singleton () {}
  public static Singleton getInstance () {
    return InstanceHolder.INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

Initialization of class variables is implicitly synchronized by the class loader. By using the inner class Singleton-Constructor, it’s only called during the initialization of the inner class in the `getInstance` method.

I hope this helps you. And sorry for my bad english if you need more information just post a comment.

Comment: _In this case it could be that more than one thread work with the same instance._  Sounds like a problem, but isn't that the reason to use a singleton in the first place? The **real problem** of the first example is quite different but very bad: If more than one thread execute `getInstance` simultaneously for the first time, the constructor of Singleton` is called more than once (this could very well happen, if construction of the singleton is not trivial). So the singleton would not be a singleton and subsequent errors are **very hard to detect**.

Comment: That’s why I wouldn’t recommend using the first example. As you have seen it could gave problems when more than one Thread works with it. As an example if the progress needs a initialisation in the Constructor. And he starts the Progress and an anther Thread want’s to access while he is in the initialisation the secend Thread would get a half-baked Instance. The Problem with errors like that is that they are very hard to find, just like you sad it and you didn’t get them always at the same time.

Comment: I don't think so there is any problem with the first solution. 1st solution solves the problem the question asks for i.e. make it thread safe. Although, it results in performance cost of blocking other threads but definitely will work according to the question asked. Correct me if my understanding is wrong. 
Second solution is not always desirable because most of the times, our initialisation codes requires some resources that are not available at class level initialisation otherwise second solution is also applicable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the examples and the explanation. So The singleton pattern is the recommended way and 'synchronized' could possible be to weak to solve my [lucene problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880347/why-did-lucene-indexwriter-did-not-update-the-index-when-called-from-a-web-modul) .

Answer (score 0):

Singleton pattern is one object concept across jvm or application instance, whereas synchronized is a keyword in java to for mutual exclusion. Please elaborate your problem.